# Disallow certain page directories but NOT that page itself

Tags: robots.txt

Let's say, I have a dynamic page that creates `URL's` from user inputs.
For example: `www.XXXXXXX.com/browse` <-------- (Browse being the page)

Every time user enters some query, it generates more pages.
For example: `www.XXXXXXX.com/browse/abcd` <-------- (abcd being the new page)

Now, I want Google to do crawl this "browse" page but not the sub
pages generated by it.

I'm thinking of adding this to my robots.txt page; "Disallow: /browse/"

Would that be the right thing to do? or will it also prevent the
Googlebot from crawling the "browse" page? What should I do to get the
optimal result?

Comment: I believe you can use the meta tag 'no index, no follow' on your inner pages, and just use 'no follow' on your main pages, so google will not 'go in' more...http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html

Comment: These sub pages are like in hundreds, I don't think I can add no follow to every page manually :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URL doesn't end with slash:

```
www.XXXXXXX.com/browse
```

Therefore this code should work:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /browse/
```

Comment: That's what I've been thinking. I have a doubt though, Are you sure that it will not block the page "browse" itself?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Because disallow contains a trailing slash.

Comment: Well thanks a lot.
Just for the knowledge, so if I had to disallow only the browse, I would need not to put "/" at the end and that's it?

Comment: @RajSandhu: In your question, the example URL *does* end with a slash (`www.XXXXXXX.com/browse/`). Is this intentional? If yes, the robots.txt suggested by znurgl would of course also block it.

Comment: @unor No, that was not intentional. I'm confused now :/ What am I ought to do

Comment: @RajSandhu: Well, you removed the trailing slash now from your question. If your actual URL really is `example.com/browse` (without trailing slash), then znurgl’s robots.txt will work.